# Python packaging: understanding root folder, importing from package files,

Tags: pandas, debugging, import, package

I would like to understand better how importing within a module works, and how to remove an error entry in my code analysis.

I have a package structure

```
/packagename
├─ /src
    ├─ /utils
    |    ├─ __init__.py
    |    └─ utils.py
    ├─ __init__.py
    ├─ main.py
```

in my `main.py` file, one of the first lines reads

[image]

where you note the code analysis of PyCharm cannot find the `utils` folder. However, when running/ debugging to this line, it executes with no problem:

[image: import executes without error, despite IDE code analysis error]

I found putting a dot in front of the folder remove the code analysis error:

[image: debugger settings]

but ultimately results in

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

when executing the code. Here are the debugging settings:

[image]

do these settings adhere to best practice python standard?

TLDR; stuff works without the dot before `utils`, but I'd like to understand how I can fix the error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An absolute import specifies the resource to be imported using its full path from the project’s root folder.

- Example:

```
from package1 import module1
from package1.module2 import function1
```

A relative import specifies the resource to be imported relative to the current location—that is, the location where the import statement is.

- Example:

```
from .some_module import some_class
from ..some_package import some_function
```

- My suggestion: Use the absolute import method.

You start by typing the path in your project root.

Comment: thanks! i changed the line from `from utils.uttils import *`to `from src.utils.uttils import *`
and it works.